# Creating a schemamigration for CharField vs BooleanField has different output, why?

Tags: django, django-south

**I. Suppose you have the following model:**

```
class Knight(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    of_the_round_table = models.BooleanField()
```

**II. Now you add this model to south's schemamigration and migrate:**

```
python manage.py schemamigration myapp --initial
python manage.py migrate myapp
```

**III. You create an entry in the `Knight` table:**

```
>>> jason = Knight.objects.get(name=”Jason”)
```

Nothing out of the ordinary here, just the regular routine. However notice the following.

**IV-A. Add a new model field (`CharField`):**

```
class Knight(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    of_the_round_table = models.BooleanField()
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100) # +
```

**V-A. Write a schemamigration for this new field:**

```
$ python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
 ? The field 'Knight.surname' does not have a default specified, yet is NOT NULL.
 ? Since you are adding this field, you MUST specify a default
 ? value to use for existing rows. Would you like to:
 ?  1. Quit now, and add a default to the field in models.py
 ?  2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now
```

**BUT**

Now let's try step IV and V again but with a `BooleanField` instead of a `CharField`

**IV-B. Add a new model field (`BooleanField`):**

```
class Knight(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    of_the_round_table = models.BooleanField()
    has_sword = models.BooleanField() # +
```

**V-B. Write a schemamigration for this new field:**

```
$ python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto
 + Added field has_sword on registration.Knight
Created 0005_auto__add_field_knight_has_sword.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate registration
```

*Q1 : Why do I get a different output for adding a `BooleanField`(`V-B`) than for adding a `CharField`(`V-A`) even though [according to the Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null) both these fields have `null=False` by default?*

*Q2 : How are you supposed to know which fields will give an output like `BooleanField` and which ones will give an output like `CharField` when you apply `python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto` to a model in the given circumstance?*

I'm using `SQlite` as RDBMS and `Django 1.4` btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because in Django up to version 1.5, `BooleanField` uses `False` as an implicit default value. That is [going to change in Django 1.6](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6/#booleanfield-no-longer-defaults-to-false).

So while your `CharField` does not have a default value specified, forcing South to prompt you for it, `BooleanField` does have a default value, even if implicit.

Comment: Aha ok, so in the case I've given any other field but `BooleanField` would generate the same output as `CharField` (For Django 1.4).